# Почему может возникать ошибка MSB6006("CL.exe" завершилась с кодом 2)

Tags: c++

После написания кода, во время компиляции вылезла ошибка "CL.exe" завершилась с кодом 2. Подскажите, из-за чего она может возникать?

Comment: Посмотрите список ошибок - неужели просто завершение, без сообщений об ошибках?

Comment: да. 1 ошибка (+ 6 предупреждений + 2 сообщения)

Comment: Ну вот из-за ошибки + 6 предупреждений она и возникает... Исправьте ошибку. Код 2 - это ошибки в программе.

Answer (score 0):

Если верить [этому форуму](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/b935249a-b155-46d1-83d9-e4c93fee0d83/105410961080107310821072-108910731086108810821080-msb6006?forum=vsru), можно поискать кириллические символы в коде.

Comment: При чем тут  это? Код 2 вполне вызываем ошибками в программе...

Comment: @Harry, возможно я неправильно погуглил, но я понял, что 2 - это internal compiler error?

Comment: Значит, у меня при любой ошибке в программе вылетает  internal compiler error... Я обычно для несложных программ работаю из редактора fte, и сообщение `status=2` у меня перед глазами всякий раз, когда какая-то очепятка в коде :) Еще раз - не гуглил, чисто практика...

Comment: @Harry, ну значит я неправильно понял. Список кодов возврата не гуглится...

Comment: @Harry при обычной ошибки компиляции было бы не MSB6006, а нормальное сообщение об ошибке с кодом, начинающимся с "С". Это действительно больше похоже на внутреннюю ошибку.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight В любом случае нужно начинать с устранения ошибок ("*1 ошибка (+ 6 предупреждений + 2 сообщения) *") в коде.